# Find eigen values of a block-diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose we have a block-diagonal matrix $A_{n\times n}$ which consists of the block
\begin{bmatrix}
n-1 && 1\\ 
1 && n-1\end{bmatrix}

appearing  $p$ times, and $ nI_{n-2p}$ appearing once.

> Find eigen values of $A$.

By computing eigen values of \begin{bmatrix}
n-1 && 1\\ 
1 && n-1\end{bmatrix} we have the eigen values  $n$ and $n-2$ appearing only once.

Hence the eigen values will be $1.n \rightarrow p $ times and $2.n-2 \rightarrow p $times

and from $ nI_{n-2p}$ we have eigen value $n$ appearing $n-2p$ times.

**But the answer given is**

The
eigenvalues of $A$ are $n-2$ with multiplicity $p$; and $n$ with multiplicity $n- p$.

Where am I wrong ?Please help in this matter.I am really stuck here.

Comment: Your answer is fine: $p+(n-2p)=n-p$.

Comment: What is $(n-2p)+p$?

Comment: Oh Gotcha! thanks @Jonas@J.M.